# How do i count duplicate lines in a file and find how many times each line was duplicated?

Tags: python, list, readfile

I want to read a file of all time winners in the World Series.

I have a list that I pre-sorted below;

```
New York Yankees
New York Yankees
New York Yankees
Oakland Athletics
Oakland Athletics
Oakland Athletics
Oakland Athletics
Philadelphia Athletics
```

I want to find out how many times "New York Yankees" "Oakland Athletics" and "Philadelphia Athletics" are repeated throughout the file while maintaining the integrity of the Alphabetical order.

With an end result of;

```
New York Yankees         3
Oakland Athletics        4
Philadelphia Athletics   1
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do i delete this? and yes that answers my question

Comment: Na. I'd just leave it up. It will act as pointer to the correct, original question. And by the way, thank-you for your service!(I read your bio).

Comment: @leaf not a problem at all man....I loved the service, I just don't trust the candidates of the presidential elections 2016 to be who is pointing fingers on where I would most likely go.... :P So I decided to get out and keep my family close ;)

Comment: Nothing wrong with that man ;)